# How to make my app loads the articles from the beginning?

Tags: java, android

I have a simple app with 50 articles, my previous and next button work good in all choices BUT when the user goes to the end (at 50th article) the app can't load again from the beginning the 1st article.
Thanks for any help, here is my code:
I don't know if needs more cede for to be clear, cause I am a newbie.

```
public class StoryActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String TAG = StoryActivity.class.getSimpleName();


    private Story mStory = new Story();

    private ImageView mImageView;
    private TextView mTextView;
    private Page mCurrentPage;
    private String mName;
    private Button mPreviousButton;
    private Button mNextButton;
    private ScrollView mScrollView;
    private Button mStartButton;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_story2);

      //Intent intent = getIntent();
       //mName = intent.getStringExtra(getString(R.string.key_name));

        if(mName == null){
            mName = "";
        }

        Log.d(TAG, mName);

        mImageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.storyImageView);
        mTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.storyTextView);
       mPreviousButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.previousButton);
       mNextButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.nextButton);

        mTextView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());

        loadPage(0);
    }
    private void loadPage(int choice){
     mCurrentPage = mStory.getPage(choice);

        Drawable drawable  = getResources().getDrawable(mCurrentPage.getImageId());
        mImageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);

        String pageText = mCurrentPage.getText();
        //add the name if placeholder included.
       //pageText  = String.format(pageText,mName);
        mTextView.setText(pageText);

        if(mCurrentPage.isSingle()){
            mPreviousButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mNextButton.setText("");
            mNextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    loadPage(0);
                }
            });

        }else{

            mPreviousButton.setText(mCurrentPage.getChoices().getText1());
            mNextButton.setText(mCurrentPage.getChoices().getText2());

            mPreviousButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    int previousPage = mCurrentPage.getChoices().getPreviousPage();
                    loadPage(previousPage);
                }
            });

            mNextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int nextPage = mCurrentPage.getChoices().getNextPage();
                loadPage(nextPage);
            }
        });
    }}
}
```

Comment: Why not just set the current page to one on the last page?

Comment: when you are showing page 50, what will be the value of `mCurrentPage.getChoices().getNextPage()`?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, could you tell me how to do this?